# Singular value perturbation inequality

Tags: inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory, matrix-norms

Need some help with this one.

Given $A,E \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.  Show that
$$\sigma_{\max}(A+E) \leq \sigma_{\max}(A) + \|E\|_2 $$

The hint provided is:  $$\sigma_{\min}(A)\|x\|_2 \leq \|Ax\|_2 \leq \sigma_{\max}(A)\|x\|_2$$

With the hint, I have tried
\begin{align}
\sigma_{\max}(A+E)\|x\|_2 &\leq \|(A+E)x\|_2 \\
&\leq \|Ax\|_2 + \|Ex\|_2 \\
\sigma_{\min}(A+E) &\leq \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\||x\|_2} + \frac{\|Ex\|_2}{\|x\|_2} \\
&\leq \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2} + \|E\|_2 
\end{align}

Am I on the right track?  How can I get $\sigma_{\max}(A)$ into this inequality?

Comment: If $m\neq n$, there are no eigenvalues.

Comment: My mistake, should be singular value.  I will correct

Comment: Isn't $\|\cdot\|_2$ the same as $\sigma_{\max}(\cdot)$? Or are they different?

Comment: yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already shown
$$\frac{\|(A+E)x\|_2}{\|x\|_2} \le \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2} + \frac{\|Ex\|_2}{\|x\|_2} \le \sigma_{\max}(A) + \sigma_{\max}(E)$$
for all nonzero $x$.

Note that when $x$ is the right singular vector of $A+E$ corresponding to its maximum singular value, then the left-hand side is $\sigma_{\max}(A+E)$.

Comment: I think I had that at one point!  :) thank you

Answer (score -1):

without the hint we can still prove it like this:

since $\sigma_{max}(A) = \lVert A \rVert_{2}$ and $\sigma_{max}(A + E) = \lVert A + E \rVert_{2}$,

then by triangular inequality(definition of matrix norm), we have

$\lVert A + E\rVert_{2} \leq \lVert A \rVert_{2} + \lVert E\rVert_{2}$,

i.e. $\sigma_{max}(A + E) \leq \sigma_{max}(A) + \lVert E\rVert_{2}$.

P.S. have you tried to prove $\sigma_{min}(A + E) \geq \sigma_{min}(A) - \lVert E\rVert_{2}$?

my method seems cannot prove this statement.